# Tenants want to use web api directly in Abp Framework

Tags: abp

Our Tenant want to use our abp web api directly. which method should be used for authentication(login)? if I use "/api/account/login" then I have to give tenantId to my tenant. is it a good decision or is there a way of using an api key for accessing abp web api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the authentication part, they should use one of the authentication flows. For your case, client secret or resource owner password flows seems fine. You will create a client in the IdentityServer and share client id & secret with your partner. There are some libraries for the authentication, based on the client platform (.net, Java, JavaScript... etc).

You can refer to the IDS4 documentation: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

Once you obtain the access code, you can add it to the Authorization header (manually or using a library).

For the tenant part, they can send `__tenant` [HTTP header](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy#determining-current-tenant-from-web-request). This value can be tenant id or tenant name. So, you don't have to share the id, tenant name will work as expected.